# Can you figure out the system requirements for an application using performance testing tools?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am working on the performance testing and wants to know if there is a way we can figure out that If my performance test execution can tell the favourable system requirements for an application for which I am running the test.
e.g. If I run a performance test on a windows 10 machine which have 4gb ram and I am running test for 100 users then at the end of the test, the tool can suggest me to use a higher version of ram like 8gb ram.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct relationship between hardware resources and performance, you cannot predict or extrapolate existing results like this:

- on 4 GB ram the system supports 100 users without issues
- it means that on 8 GB ram it will support 200 users and on 16 GB RAM it will support 400 users

**it doesn't work that way **

You can conduct some [scalability testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing) to see how metrics and KPIs change on different hardware setups.

The only way to state how the system will behave on this or that hardware configuration is running a test against particular this configuration, i.e.:

- set up monitoring of essential resources usage like CPU, RAM, Disk, Network, Swap, etc. If you don't have better candidates - you can use [JMeter PerMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for this
- start your test with 1 user and gradually increase the load at the same time looking at resources consumption
- when any of monitored resources utilization starts exceeding i.e. 80% of maximum available capacity - stop your test and check how many users were active at this stage using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/) plugin - this is how many users your system can support on this configuration of hardware/software. If anything changes - you will need to re-run your test

Comment: Thank you! Well that ease my task. I was thinking some what similar approach and thanks for the plugin link.